# Cannot save tables with get() in R

Tags: r, error-handling, get, save

I scan through SQL database and load evey table by ODBC then would like to store it in a file of file name same as table name. I compose *filename* by `paste(path,variablename,Sys.Date(),sep="_")`. I also like to distinguish data in R by storing value of tables in a variable of same name as corresponding SQL table. I achieve this by loading data to a temporary variable then assigning its content to a variable which name is stored in *variablename* with `assign(variablename,temporarytable)` function.

I would like to save an R variable with save() function, but need to refer to its name stored in *variablename* variable. When using `get(variablename)` I got its content. When using `save(get(variablename),file=paste(...,variablename,...))` I got an error that the object ‘get(variablename)’ cannot be found.

What is the problem with get() in save()? How can I get a variable content saved in this situation?

ps
I scan through SQL database tables with `for` loop. *variablename* variable stores SQL table name in particular iteration. `assign(variablename,temporarytable)` helped to load data to an object of required name.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved like this:

```
save(list = variablename, file = paste(...,variablename,...))
```

But I would still itch to know why `save(get(variablename), ...)` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can save the data to an object.

```
temp <- get(variablename)
save(temp,file=file.path(...,variablename,...))
```

Comment: Not good. Saved objects remember its name. In this method when loading object later on I will get "temp" as its name. But I would like to have object name same as SQL table name corresponding to its content.